# How to pass multiple arguments to prompt in Linux command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, command-line

If Linux command has single prompt then we can handle it like following -

```
echo "password" | sudo -S ls
```

But `startWebLogic.sh` has two prompts, one for username and other for password to boot WebLogic server.

I tried with following

```
sh startWebLogic.sh << EOF
> user
> password
> EOF
```

but it end up with following which indicates command did not succeed

```
<Aug 31, 2020 7:04:59 PM GMT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to FORCE_SHUTTING_DOWN.>
Stopping Derby server...
Derby server stopped.
```

Can you please suggest how I can pass two arguments of prompt in single command?

Answer (score 0):

What I would try:

```
{
    echo username
    sleep 1
    echo passwd
} | bash startWebLogic.sh
```